# Input string was not in a correct format error on using int keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

First i want to assure you that i have already read many posts with similar title on SO.

I have created an ASP.NET MVC project and changed the keys of template tables to int following this article

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

But i am getting a runtime error in this line of StartUp.Auth.cs

```
getUserIdCallback: (id) => (id.GetUserId<int>()))
```

Error = System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I know it's a late response. But for people who may encounter this in the future: Clear your cache or switch to a different browser.

Although you changed the pk from `string` to `int` in the code and updated `Identity` related tables, the cookie was still the one you logged in with string pks.

Comment: I also had to delete the existing database entries. Then it worked

Comment: New browser works for me, but clearing cache doesn't. I even changed the port on which it runs and it still bugs out

Comment: @Zapnologica did you delete existing database entries?

Comment: Is there not a solution that one can do server side, where the cookie is just rejected because its invalid and then takes the user to login screen?

Answer (score 7):

To get rid of this error you need to clear cookies for your site.

Chrome: F12 -> Application -> Storage -> Cookies -> your site -> Clear

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and got sick or resetting my cache. I think either my cookie was becoming invalid or the cookie changed and for some reason it couldn't be parsed anymore.

I found a solution in a GitHub repository issue:
https://github.com/TypecastException/AspNet-Identity-2-With-Integer-Keys/issues/2#issuecomment-128280883

Using the following code fixed my issue

```
getUserIdCallback: (id) => GrabUserId(id))

public static int GrabUserId(System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity claim)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(claim.GetUserId(), out int id))
        return 0;
    else
        return id;
}
```

When returning 0 it just logs you out because it couldn't recognize you as a user.

Answer (score 1):

I really didn't want to change the taste of my browser experience. So, in my case, from the **Chrome DevTools (F12)** > **Application** > **Clear Storage** > **Clear site data** fixed it.

[image]